Do laws like those used on Pavel Durov apply to tor nodes?
Pavel Durov is being held in relation to laws breached by Telegram, probably including  Digital Services Act.  Further details, but no explicit laws are available here.  The UK has similar laws, such as the Online Safety Bill.  I asked previously abut the applicability of this law to decentralised services such as a mastodon server, and the answer was that the Online Safety Bill applies.
Another solution that would not expose the server hosts to this sort of danger would be Veilid, but this could just push the problem to tor nodes.
Do laws such as the EU Digital Services Act and the UK Online Safety Bill apply to tor nodes?

Do you know which specific laws he allegedly broke? The article you linked to is not very specific, it just says "his messaging app facilitates criminality including money laundering and drug trafficking." Later it says the issue is lack of moderation.

@Barmar I do not.  The article I choose because it does at least mention the Digital Services Act which is suspected to be the main one AIUI.

@Barmar I have added the Prosecutors statment

You should include the appropriate quotes from the link you added so that people don't need to go to a third party site to see what you are asking about or if the link is removed.

Not to mention that it's in French.
